# Smoky lights at events - Piped in or a chemistry reaction of some kind?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

Was at Dreamhack MTL this weekend and realised that in the whole venue there seems to be just a little bit of smoke in the spotlights and other light sources.

You also see that kind of smoke in shows and conventions. So I was wondering is that smoke something that gets piped in for that volumic effect on the lights, or is it just something that tends to happen when you shove 3000+ human beings in an enclosed space?

And if so, what is happening here, on a chemistry level, to cause that smoke?